# HTML button text alignment in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Using this CSS:

```
button {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I am unable to align certain text properly in Firefox.  For example:

Firefox (38.0.5)

[image]

Chrome

[image]

The horizontal alignment of the [+] button is off in Firefox, but not in Chrome?  What's going on and how can I fix it?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oge3tg3n/2/

Comment: Weird, works fine here in FF, Chrome, Opera. Latest versions. Are you using some sort of CSS framework?

Comment: Just tested in chrome and FF, works fine

Comment: @Mikey Apparently it was an issue with version 38.  Just installed 39 (the most current) and the problem went away.  No framework -- should be reproducible in 38.

Comment: @whiskeyspider Ok. Did you find it in the change log?

Answer (score 1):

If you increase the height and width to 27px, the alignment will be centered in both firefox and chrome.

```
button {
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 27px;
   width: 27px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding: 0;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Tested in firefox 38.0.5.